# Declaring static class variables

Tags: c++

I have class with static string variable `m`.

```
class turbo
 {
 public:
 static string m;
 }
```

if I not declare like defined below I will get `error undefined reference turbo::m`.

```
string turbo::m;
```

Why I should declare it twice? I don't need to declare non static variables second time. Where is logic?

Comment: You should declare it once, and define it once. That last line is the definition.

Comment: "Where is logic?" - the logic is that there's difference between "declaration" and "definition".

Comment: `I don't need to declare non static variables second time` You kind of do. If it's a global variable that you want to make available to multiple source files, then you declare it once in a header with `extern`, and then define it once in one source file.

Comment: It is not obvious at all that the first occurrence is just a declaration and not a definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I was surprised by this too the first time,
but found the very reasonable reason for it.

while member variables are stored within the object allocated space,
static members are not placed within the object memory space (either heap or stack)
but have a private shared space. just like functions do.

Therefore, declaring the `static string m` within the class.
is just like saying: there is a shared definition of this somewhere
and the name is  `turbo::m`.

Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

It's the difference between declaration and definition, very much like declaring a function with a forward reference, e.g.;

```
int MyFuncion();
```

and actually defining it with its function body, e.g.,

```
int MyFunction()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I know you have an object and not a function, but conceptually, the declaration/definition idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

C++ forbids the definition of non-const static data members in the body of a class ("inline definition").  It becomes more obvious if you try to use an explicit constructor: for example,

```
class turbo
{
public:
    static string m;
    static string s = string("my_str"); // doesn't work
}
```

Hence, when you write `static string m` in the body of a class, it is merely a declaration, not a definition.  You will have to define it later:

```
static string turbo::s = string("my_str");
```

In your case, you are simply invoking the default constructor in the definition:

```
static string turbo::m; // calls the default constructor
```

(Like any static variable, initialization occurs at the very start of your program, before `main`.)

Note that the definition must also occur only once (to avoid multiple definitions), so it must not appear in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

In the class definition you only declare the static variable

```
class turbo
 {
 public:
 static string m;
 }
```

but it is not yet defined. To define the corresponding object you have to write

```
string turbo::m;
```

Now it will exist regardless of whether instances of the class were created.